# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 ERROR

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an issue with my app when retrieving data from array.

**SchedulePage:**

```
    public class SchedulePage extends Activity {

    List<MyTask> tasks;
    List<Test_Sched> SchedList;
//  Intent intent = getIntent();
//  String Username = intent.getStringExtra("Username2");
    int Count = 0;
    String SendCount = "";

    TextView endtv, durationtv;


    //storage of Test_Name 
    private static ArrayList<String> Test_Name = new ArrayList<String>();

    //storage of x values in array private 
    private static ArrayList<Integer> Duration = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule_page);

        endtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Endtv);
        durationtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Durationtv);

        //Use this to Create Layouts Dynamically
        //RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        GetSchedule();

        //GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        //gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));


        //Storing test name Arraylist in a array
        final String [] web = Test_Name.toArray(new String[Test_Name.size()]);

        //Storing images  in a array
        ArrayList<Integer> imagesAL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < Test_Name.size(); i++){
        //  String testname = web[i];
            String lf = "One Leg(Left)", rf = "One Leg(Right)", sf = "Separate Foot", sbsf= "Side By Side Foot", tthr ="Toe To Heel(Right)", tthl ="Toe To Heel(Left)";

            if(lf.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.leftfoot);
            }
            if(rf.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.rightfoot);
            }
            if(sf.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.feetapart);

            }
            if(sbsf.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.sidebysidefoot);

            }
            if(tthr.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.righttoetoleftheel);
            }
            if(tthl.equals(Test_Name.get(i))){
                imagesAL.add(R.drawable.lefttoetorightheel);
            }
            }

        Integer [] imageId = imagesAL.toArray(new Integer[imagesAL.size()]);

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(SchedulePage.this, web, imageId);
        GridView grid;
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(SchedulePage.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Login Stuff

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getDuration() {
          return Duration;
       }

    public static ArrayList<String> getTestName() {
          return Test_Name;
       }

    private void GetSchedule(){
    String jsonOutput = "http://172.20.34.112/IBBTS_WebService_MobileAndDevice/Service1.asmx/GetSchedule";

    if (isOnline()) {
        //while(End == "not yet"){
        requestData(jsonOutput);
        //}
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(SchedulePage.this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
    private static String doJSONHTTPCall(String urlStr) {
        String output2 = "";
        try {

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(urlStr);
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw e;
            }
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                output2 += output;
            }

            conn.disconnect();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output2;
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        //Send the integer to String
        Bundle gt=getIntent().getExtras();
        String usernamePass =gt.getString("userName2");
        SendCount = Integer.toString(Count);
        RequestPackage p = new RequestPackage();
        p.setMethod("GET");
        p.setUri(uri);
        p.setParam("Username", usernamePass);

        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(p);
        }

    protected void updateDisplay(){

        if (SchedList != null) {
            for (Test_Sched test_Sched : SchedList) {
                Duration.add(test_Sched.getDuration());
                Test_Name.add(test_Sched.getTest_Name());
                Count++;
            }
            }

    }

    protected boolean isOnline() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo  = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<RequestPackage, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //updateDisplay("Starting Task");

            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                //progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            tasks.add(this);
        }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {

                String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
                return content;

            }

            @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                SchedList = ScheduleJSONParser.parseFeed(result);
                updateDisplay();
                tasks.remove(this);
                if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                    //progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                }
            @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                    //updateDisplay(values[0]);
                }
        }
}
```

**ScheduleJSONParsor**

```
public class ScheduleJSONParser {

public static List<Test_Sched> parseFeed(String content) {

    try {
        JSONArray ar = new  JSONArray(content);
        List<Test_Sched> SchedList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
            Test_Sched test_Sched = new Test_Sched();

            test_Sched.setDuration(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("Duration")));
            test_Sched.setTest_Name(obj.getString("Test_Name"));

            SchedList.add(test_Sched); 

        }

        return SchedList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}}
```

The logcat does not indicate which line has the error and I find it difficult to troubleshoot.
The idea is that it retrieves the schedule from the database and pass it to an array. then the app will display image buttons for each of the exercise name.

Also when I click the schedulePage button from the main menu, it shows up blank and I have to re-click the schedulePage the second time. The second time shows the arrayoutofbounds error..

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is means you are trying to get value from array that is grater than the array size , debug your app and find out where is the problem

Comment: try to use `ar.size()` instead of `ar.length()`

Comment: Surround your code with `try { ... } catch (Exception e)` and print out the error for yourself.

Comment: @Hacketo, I can't change it to ar.size() because the ar is a JSONarray.

Comment: @ZakiAhmadSahri depend on which package JSONArray come from

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this both lines

```
GetSchedule();

final String [] web = Test_Name.toArray(new String[Test_Name.size()]);
```

in `GetSChedule()` you are running thread in background and from response of webservice you are filling `Test_Name` array. But before calling webservice you are copying `Test_Name` data to  web array, so your web[] will be blank because there is no data in `Test_Name`.

Make `web[]` global

```
String [] web;
```

fill it in `updateDisplay()`

```
protected void updateDisplay(){
    if (SchedList != null) {
        for (Test_Sched test_Sched : SchedList) {
            Duration.add(test_Sched.getDuration());
            Test_Name.add(test_Sched.getTest_Name());
            Count++;
        }
        web = Test_Name.toArray(new String[Test_Name.size()]);
        }

}
```

Comment: hi, I tried changing the code but I got another error: ` 11-25 04:34:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(5687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ibbts/com.example.ibbts.SchedulePage}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: when I click on the schedule page it gives the error.

Comment: yes but where, which line, atleast you should know something

Comment: when I click on the SchedulePage it gives the error, can't open the page. The logcat does not mention the line that is causing it, it only mentions the   page that caused the problem which was the SchedulePage. @Ravi Rupareliya.